# this within a loop in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im making a quiz. I need to loop through an array of options which are `<li>` and add a click event listener to the correct answer. In the code below the correct answer is 5 but in reality it will change. So I need to add the click event listener to the 5th `<li>`.

```
var someFunction = function() {
    var correctAnswerNo = "5";
    var options = optionsContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(correctAnswerNo);
        if (correctAnswerNo === i) {
            console.log(this);
            // here is where I will put my event listener 
        }
    }
}
```

When I log out `correctAnswerNo` and `i` it works as expected. However when I log `this` then I get undefined. I need to access `this` to add the click event to it.

Comment: you don't need to loop. just get the 5th element with `options[4]` (index starts with 0, that's why 4 is the 5th element)

Comment: _but in reality it will change_ - if it's not hardcoded, use `options[i].addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: rather than adding event listener to `this`, add it to `options[i]` inside the `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding event listener to `this`, add it to `options[i]` inside the `if`

Your `if` condition will be something like

```
if (correctAnswerNo === i) {
  options[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("correct answer");
  });
}
```